# Command line query to linkdecrypter

Tags: command-line, javascript

I would like to create an script that I can run from my bash command line to make a query to the service given in the webpage http://linkdecrypter.com/

For instance I would like to run something like

> script http://uploadmirrors.com/download/1BJMEVHM/

and get as an answer the list of urls as is provided using the webservice

Unfortunately, I do not see how to do this (I am completely unfamiliar with the "post" method that is used in that webpage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API -> http://linkdecrypter.com/?a

```
$ wget -q -O - "http://linkdecrypter.com/api/?t=link&url=http://uploadmirrors.com/download/1BJMEVHM/" > your_links.txt
```